# how deterring the index of a column under some conditiones?

Tags: pandas

how I can do the following in pandas. let's I have a column which has an index. I want to find the index in `col1` and do the following:

- If 3 rows above the index and 3 rows below the index, the sign of the values of `col1` was constant and it changes in one of these rows and remains constant after the point pick the index of the row that the sign changes. If there is not such a point pick the value of index column.

It is hard to explain but I think it is more clearer in an example:

consider the following data:

```
ind_column     col1
4             0.5
4             0.65
4             0.6
4             0.2
4             0.1
4             0.8
4             -0.3
4             -0.2
4             -0.3
```

here, the index column is 4, so we look at 3 rows before 4 and 3 rows after 4. Basically rows: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. We see that in rows 6th the sign changed, since all signs are the same before this point (positive) and after this point (negative) the index 6th is selected.

Now lets consider the following data

```
ind_column     col1
5             0.5
5             0.65
5             -0.6
5             0.2
5             -0.1
5             0.8
5             0.3
5             -0.2
5             -0.3
```

Now we should look at the rows 2,3,4,5,6,7,8. Since the sign is changing in these rows more than once, the index 5 is celected.

in the following data also index 5 is selected since the sign never changes.

```
ind_column     col1
5             0.5
5             0.65
5             0.6
5             0.2
5             0.1
5             0.8
5             0.3
5             0.2
5             0.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_index(df):
    idx = df.loc[0,'ind_column']
    tmp = np.sign(df.iloc[max(idx-3,0):idx+4]['col1']).diff().dropna().ne(0)
    if tmp.sum() == 1:
        return tmp[tmp].index.item()
    return idx

indices = [get_index(df) for df in [df1,df2,df3]] # see `dfs` listed below

print(indices)
[6, 5, 5]
```

**Explanation**

- Inside the function, we first retrieve the "start" index from column `ind_column` (e.g. `4` or `5` in the example `dfs`).
- Next, we use [`df.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to select the index range -3 rows through to (and including) +3 rows from `idx` value. We use `max(idx-3,0)` to ensure that we won't be trying to select a negative index value (i.e. when `idx < 3`) as the starting point, causing an empty `df` selection.
- From the `df` slice, we select column `col1` and apply [`np.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) to get a series with `-1`, `0` or `1`.
- Now, we chain [`Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) to get the difference between consecutive rows, and use [`Series.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) to get rid of the first row, which will be `NaN` by definition.
- Finally, we chain [`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) with `0`. This will get us the series with booleans: `True` where there is a switch in sign, `False` where there is no switch.
- The resulting `pd.Series` is stored as `tmp` and now, we simply have to check whether the `sum` of the series equals `1`. If it does, we want to get the index of the `True` value responsible, returning `tmp[tmp].index.item()`. In all other cases, we either have no switches at all, or multiple ones. In both cases, we simply want to return `idx`.

**Data used for `df1, df2, df3` above**

```
data1 = {'ind_column': {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 4, 4: 4, 5: 4, 6: 4, 7: 4, 8: 4}, 
        'col1': {0: 0.5, 1: 0.65, 2: 0.6, 3: 0.2, 4: 0.1, 5: 0.8, 6: -0.3, 
                 7: -0.2, 8: -0.3}}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'ind_column': {0: 5, 1: 5, 2: 5, 3: 5, 4: 5, 5: 5, 6: 5, 7: 5, 8: 5}, 
         'col1': {0: 0.5, 1: 0.65, 2: -0.6, 3: 0.2, 4: -0.1, 5: 0.8, 6: 0.3, 
                  7: -0.2, 8: -0.3}}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

data3 = {'ind_column': {0: 5, 1: 5, 2: 5, 3: 5, 4: 5, 5: 5, 6: 5, 7: 5, 8: 5}, 
         'col1': {0: 0.5, 1: 0.65, 2: 0.6, 3: 0.2, 4: 0.1, 5: 0.8, 6: 0.3,
                  7: 0.2, 8: 0.3}}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)
```